# How do I add a global Gorm constraint to Grails 3 application.yml?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I want to add a global constraint to application.yml to make all fields in a domain class able to be null or blank. But I can't seem to get the syntax right. My domain class has about 30 fields and I want to avoid having to set constraints individually for every field. The examples on the Grails/Gorm site only show the old application.groovy syntax, below. I want to use application.yml instead:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable: true, size: 1..20)
}
```

I've tried variations of the following in application.yml, but get runtime exceptions when starting my Grails app.

```
grails:
    gorm:
      default:
        constraints:  '*' (nullable: true, blank: true)
```

Below is an example of the runtime exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load application metadata: while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 137, column 9:
            constraints:  '*' nullable: true ... 
        ^
expected <block end>, but found Scalar in 'reader', line 137, column 27:
        constraints:  '*' nullable: true, blank: true
```

Does anyone have a good example of the syntax for application.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `application.groovy` file in `grails-app/conf/` and specify it there.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why I didn't find it in my original search. Like some of the commenters in the other question, I was also under the impression application.groovy was obsolete in Grails 3. But it's not.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do it in a Spring Boot application, **not** in Grails?